# additional_bq_parameters as a callable not working when streaming?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a job dataflow that use bigquery to read some data from pubsub for streaming (or gcs for batch) and then insert them into bigquery.

For batch, I am using the following step:

```
(processed_rows | "Write Full to Bigquery" >> apache_beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
    table_fn,
    schema=schema_fn,
    additional_bq_parameters=additional_bq_parameters_fn,
    write_disposition=apache_beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    create_disposition=apache_beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
    method=apache_beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.FILE_LOADS
    )
 )
```

For streaming, I have the following one:

```
(processed_rows | "Write to Bigquery Streaming" >> apache_beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
    table_fn,
    schema=schema_fn,
    additional_bq_parameters=additional_bq_parameters_fn,
    write_disposition=apache_beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    create_disposition=apache_beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
    method=apache_beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
 )
```

My fonction additional_bq_parameters_fn is as follow:

```
def additional_bq_parameters_fn(table_reference_name):
    table_name = table_reference_name.split('.')[-1]
    bq_param = MAP_TABLE_BQ_PARAM[table_name]
    return bq_param
```

Until now, it's working for the batch job but not for the streaming one where I get the following error:

> _MessageClass object argument after ** must be a mapping, not function

When I look deeper into the apache beam code, I found this in the BigQueryBatchFileLoads:

```
if callable(self._additional_bq_parameters):
  additional_parameters = self._additional_bq_parameters(destination)
```

However, I can't find anything equivalent in the streaming side.

So my question is: Did I miss somthing or is there a bug (or an incomplete feature) in the apache beam code?

If I understood correctly, then I will open ticket in the apache beam Jira.

Comment: I saw this document related to it, would you like to check it out?
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/setting-pipeline-options#python_1

Comment: 1) What data type does `additional_bq_parameters_fn` return? 2) Can you try hard coding the values for `additional_bq_parameters` in a variable instead of returning it from a function? 3) When you are calling additional_bq_parameters_fn function. How are you passing `table_reference_name` which is the required parameter in your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, additional_bq_parameters is only supported for Batch, as you've adecuately figured out. What kind of parameters are you trying yo pass?

Comment: @Ricco : I tried to hard coded and of course it works. I want something depending on the message. table_reference_name is passed by dataflow itself in the process of beam ( it works similarly for schema and table_name ). I will open a ticket on beam jira for it. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @Pablo : In my json, I have a field representing the table name. I want to take this field ( could be different for 2 messages ) and use it to insert inside the corresponding table. The problem is when this table doesn't exist, I want to created it with the correct clustering_key and partition_date_field, which is not possible in streaming actually.

Comment: I see! yes, this is a missing feature - Can you create an issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/issues - that way we can make sure to add the support for it. It also sounds like you've inspected the code, so you could also add the feature and submit a pull request to apache Beam ? : )

Comment: Thank for the confirmation. I will create the issue and hope to find time to propose a PR :)